# Please help with this equation of tension in a transverse string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, waves, string, continuum-mechanics

I always assumed tension is uniform in a wave but i  saw a question in which we had to form an equation for tension at different position and time.
The answer given was
$$ T \sqrt{ 1+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^2 }.$$
Where $T$ I assume is the uniform tension which we usually talk about.
Please help
.Sorry if there is any problem with my query.

Comment: Welcome to physice.SE. Please use [MathJax to typeset equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I've edited your question to use MathJax so that you have an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the tension with the potential energy of a stretched string. If a string under tension $T$ is slighly stretched by a distance $dl$ the work done to stretch it is $Tdl$. This assumes that the change in length is small so that the change in $T$ due to the stretch is negligible (i.e of second order in $dl$).  If the string, originally lying along the $x$, axis from $0$ to $L$, is bent so that its profile becomes   $y(x)$ the change in length is
$$
\delta L= \int_0^L \sqrt{1+\left(\frac {\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^2} dx- L
$$ so the potential energy stored in the string is
$$
T \delta L= \int_0^L T \left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac {\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^2}-1\right) dx\\
\approx \int_0^L \frac 12 T \left(\frac {\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^2dx.
$$
There are cases where we need to consider the change in $T$, but these require knowledge of the Young's modulus of the string, and this does not seem to be what you are asking about.

Note added. I just saw that I answered essentially the same quastion [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/436772/why-is-the-entirity-of-string-tension-t-included-in-the-potential-energy-of-a?rq=1).  I am getting old. I have no recollection of this previous answer....

Comment: Thanks a lot for the  answer but actually I am sure I was asked to make this equation for tension. I tried to reverse engineer this ans and it seems they have assumed that "T" is actually the horizontal component of the tension along the string and then solved for the Tension along the string. Does this make any sense according to you?

Comment: No it does not make much sense. Where did you find this claim?

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply your expression by dx/dx, it can be expresed as T(ds/dx) where the (ds) is then length of a short segment after it is tilted. This implies that the tension in each segment is proportional to the length of the segment (which is not true).

Comment: Wouldn't the expression T(ds/dx) just imply that we are solving for the orginal tension along the string and T is just the horizontal component of the tension along the string.

Comment: I would agree with Mke Stone that relating the tension to the stretch requires the use of Young's modulus.